# extract comma separated values from R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

One of the column in following dataframe has comma separated value:

Dataframe1:

```
Id        date                   price     batch          resp
uv-1      2020-01-10 15:13:16    1000      Q              ES,RT,AL
uv-2      2020-01-11 17:13:16    5000      W              ES,AL
uv-3      2020-01-12 18:13:16    2000      E              ES,RT
uv-4      2020-01-13 12:13:16    3000      R              ES,RT
uv-5      2020-01-14 13:13:16    1600      T              RT,AL
uv-6      2020-01-15 13:13:16    1600      T              ES,AL
uv-7      2020-01-17 11:13:16    1300      Y              ES,RT,AL
```

I need extract the count of `resp` value on month basis as follows.

```
                   Jan-20
batch    ES        RT      AL      Total
Q        1         1       1       1
%        100%      100%    100%    14.29%
W        1         0       1       1
%        100%      0.00%    100%   14.29% 
E        1         1       0       1
%        100%      100%    0.00%   14.29%   
R        1         1       0       1
%        100%      100%    0.00%   14.29%
T        1         1       2       2
%        50%       50%     100%    28.57%
Y        1         1       1       1
%        100%      100%    100%    14.29%
Total    6         5       5       7
Total(%) 85.71%    71.43%  71.43%  100%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With dplyr, tidyr, and lubridate, we can create two summarised data frames, one for the batches and one for the totals, and then combine them using `bind_rows`.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
```

Now create the two data frames. The first groups on month and batch, the second only on month:

```
df_batch <- df %>%
  mutate(date = as.POSIXct(date), resp=strsplit(resp, ",")) %>%
  unnest(resp) %>%
  group_by(month=month(date), batch) %>%
  count(resp) %>%
  mutate(Total=max(n), p=100*n/Total) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from=resp, values_from=c(n,p), values_fill=list(n=0, p=0)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(p_Total=100*Total/sum(Total)) %>%
  select(month,batch,starts_with("n"),Total,starts_with("p"))

df_totals <- df %>% 
  mutate(date = as.POSIXct(date), resp=strsplit(resp, ",")) %>%
  group_by(month=month(date)) %>%
  mutate(Total=n()) %>%
  unnest(resp) %>%
  count(Total, resp) %>%
  mutate(p=100*n/Total) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from=resp, values_from=c(n, p)) %>%
  mutate(batch="Total", p_Total=100)

bind_rows(df_batch, df_totals)
```

---

```
# A tibble: 7 x 10
  month batch  n_ES  n_RT  n_AL Total  p_ES  p_RT  p_AL p_Total
  <dbl> <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1     1 E         1     1     0     1 100   100     0      14.3
2     1 Q         1     1     1     1 100   100   100      14.3
3     1 R         1     1     0     1 100   100     0      14.3
4     1 T         1     1     2     2  50    50   100      28.6
5     1 W         1     0     1     1 100     0   100      14.3
6     1 Y         1     1     1     1 100   100   100      14.3
7     1 Total     6     5     5     7  85.7  71.4  71.4   100
```

It's not exactly in your format provided, but the results are exactly the same and it should work for multiple months.

---

**Data**:

```
structure(list(Id = c("uv-1", "uv-2", "uv-3", "uv-4", "uv-5", 
"uv-6", "uv-7"), date = c("2020-01-10 15:13:16", "2020-01-11 17:13:16", 
"2020-01-12 18:13:16", "2020-01-13 12:13:16", "2020-01-14 13:13:16", 
"2020-01-15 13:13:16", "2020-01-17 11:13:16"), price = c(1000L, 
5000L, 2000L, 3000L, 1600L, 1600L, 1300L), batch = c("Q", "W", 
"E", "R", "T", "T", "Y"), resp = c("ES,RT,AL", "ES,AL", "ES,RT", 
"ES,RT", "RT,AL", "ES,AL", "ES,RT,AL")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: Getting error `Error in dplyr::group_by(month = month(date), batch) : 
  object 'batch' not found`

Comment: Also getting error `Error: Evaluation error: object 'N' not found.`

Comment: Are you using the data I supplied? Assign it to `df`. It's the same as the one you provided in the question.

Comment: Yes, the only change is actual datafram is that the column `resp` has ~7-8 values and has some blank as well. Also, batch column has some `NA` values which I converted to 0.

Comment: I have tried `into=c("r.1","r.2","r.3","r.4","r.5",
                                                               "r.6","r.7")` & `pivot_longer(cols=r.1:r.7)` but it is not working

Comment: Please see updated answer. I've used `strsplit` and `unnest` instead of pivoting.

Comment: Just struggling if  I can arrage column like `n_ES` then `p_ES` automatically. Not re-arrange it like `dataframe<-dataframe[,c(1000, 1:999)]`.

Comment: Yes, but I prefer dplyr verbs as they can be more convenient. For example, `select(data, ends_with("ES"), ends_with("RT"), ends_with("AL", ignore.case=FALSE), ..., ends_with("Total"))`